# How can I get jq to produce the array of values of a json dictionary?

Tags: json, jq

I have a `json` dictionary

```
$ cat foo.json
{
  "black": "#073642",
  "red": "#DC322F",
  "green": "#859900",
  "yellow": "#CF9A6B",
  "blue": "#268BD2",
  "purple": "#D33682",
  "cyan": "#2AA198",
  "white": "#EEE8D5",
  "brightBlack": "#657B83",
  "brightRed": "#D87979",
  "brightGreen": "#88CF76",
  "brightYellow": "#657B83",
  "brightBlue": "#2699FF",
  "brightPurple": "#D33682",
  "brightCyan": "#43B8C3",
  "brightWhite": "#FDF6E3",
  "foreground": "#839496",
  "background": "#002B36",
  "cursorColor": "#839496"
}
```

I would like to use `jq` to print out all of the *values* in this dictionary. So, the output should be:

```
$ jq 'magic' foo.json
#073642
#DC322F
#859900
#CF9A6B
#268BD2
#D33682
#2AA198
#EEE8D5
#657B83
#D87979
#88CF76
#657B83
#2699FF
#D33682
#43B8C3
#FDF6E3
#839496
#002B36
#839496
```

What is the `'magic'` I am looking for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This [is what `.[]` does for objects](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D):

> You can also use this on an object, and it will return all the values of the object.

To get your exact result, you would also need `jq -r`/`--raw-output` to omit the JSON string quotation marks:

```
jq -r '.[]' foo.json
```

Comment: And to print keys `jq -r 'keys_unsorted | .[]' foo.json`